# Understand maven build process

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml

I have used ant as a build tool in the past and have basic understanding of it.
Now I have started using Maven and have seen files like settings.xml, pom.xml

What are these used for? What is the best place to get started and learn the very basics of it.

As I am into front-end development and would just want to understand the basics (and not in-depth)..

Answer (score 1):

Probably this chapter for the basic `pom.xml`: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html

I think you can skip `settings.xml`, assuming that you don't plan to set up your own binary repository.

For me this is still the best place for reference: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/. Reading the whole chapter 1 is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The `settings.xml` is a file for general Maven settings and placed in the `.m2` directory in your user folder. There you would e.g. specify different profiles and repositories to use because you might have a company internal repository (A repository is where Maven gets all the dependencies from).

The `pom.xml` is placed in the root of your project folder and contains the build related information like project name, packaging, different targets and of course dependencies. It is very similar to the `build.xml` used in Ant.

For further readin I suggest the [Maven website](http://maven.apache.org/), especially the "Learning about Maven" section.